# How do you turn off Emmet abbreviations entirely?

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

Emmet abbreviations are routinely getting in my way when writing jsx/tsx code, popping up and taking precedence over methods or other completions I actually want. For instance, in this screenshot the Emmet abbreviation is getting in the way of auto-completing the `replace` method on a string:

[image]

This happens surprisingly frequently.

I don't currently use Emmet. Is there any way to turn them off entirely, or at least in `.js`, `.jsx`, `.ts`, and `.tsx` files? I've kicked around the settings a fair bit and while there are lots of Emmet-related options, I can't find a simple off switch! :-)

Comment: Did you report this as a bug? This should have never been default behavior.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph - I didn't, no. I know nothing about Emmet and have no idea whether this was completely wrong or wonderfully useful (if you use it). :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can turn emmet off in suggestions completely with:

```
{
    "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "never"
}
```

You can turn emmet off by language with:

```
 "emmet.excludeLanguages": [
    "typescriptreact", "javascriptreact"
  ],
```

Comment: **Perfect**, thank you. Was. Driving. Me. Mad. The second one does at least have a line in the settings UI (which just links to Edit in settings.json, but...). The first one doesn't even have that. :-)